# Should email password be encrypted in a django app when using TLS?

Tags: tls, email, password-management, django

I have seen multiple videos/tutorials regarding how to setup the email system in Django.

It seems that they all assume as long as the password is stored in an environmental variable, no encryption is required.

Is that so? Shouldn't passwords be encrypted? Is it because TLS provides some sort of security that makes it OK for passwords not to be encrypted?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you speaking of the password used by the Django application to send or receive emails?

Comment: Yes - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that *whenever possible*, a password should never be stored in plain text, and *whenever possible*, we should only store non invertible hashes.

But what matters in your use case is precisely *whenever possible*. A hash only allows to validate a password while you need to send it, so a hash is a no go. And the DJANGO application has to be able to access the plain text password in order to read/send emails.

Of course you could encrypt the password, but you have just put the same problem on step further: what to do with the decrypting key?

For that reason, the password has to exist somewhere in plain text, and environment variables are a nice place because the problem of reading the plain text password is left to the launching procedure which can use a privileged (system) account, while the DJANGO application should run under a non privileged one.